# How to merge 2 JSON objects from 2 files using jq?

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

I'm using the [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) tools (jq-json-processor) in shell script to parse json.

I've got 2 json files and **want to merge them into one unique file**

Here the content of files:

**file1**

```
{
    "value1": 200,
    "timestamp": 1382461861,
    "value": {
        "aaa": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        },
        "bbb": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        },
        "ccc": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        }
    }
}
```

**file2**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "timestamp": 1382461861,
    "value": {
        "aaa": {
            "value3": "v3",
            "value4": 4
        },
        "bbb": {
            "value3": "v3"
        },      
        "ddd": {
            "value3": "v3",
            "value4": 4
        }
    }
}
```

**expected result**

```
{
    "value": {
        "aaa": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2",
            "value3": "v3",
            "value4": 4
        },
        "bbb": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2",
            "value3": "v3"
        },
        "ccc": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        },
        "ddd": {
            "value3": "v3",
            "value4": 4
        }
    }
}
```

I try a lot of combinations but the only result i get is the following, which is not the expected result:

```
{
  "ccc": {
    "value2": "v2",
    "value1": "v1"
  },
  "bbb": {
    "value2": "v2",
    "value1": "v1"
  },
  "aaa": {
    "value2": "v2",
    "value1": "v1"
  }
}
{
  "ddd": {
    "value4": 4,
    "value3": "v3"
  },
  "bbb": {
    "value3": "v3"
  },
  "aaa": {
    "value4": 4,
    "value3": "v3"
  }
}
```

Using this command:

```
jq -s '.[].value' file1 file2
```

Comment: Have you tried jsontool? https://github.com/trentm/json

Comment: To do this with `json` use: `cat f1 f2 | json --deep-merge`

Comment: where/how do you get `json` @xer0x ?

Comment: @Gus oh, to get the `json` tool go to https://github.com/trentm/json

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Since 1.4 this is now possible with the `*` operator. When given two objects, it will merge them recursively. For example,

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1 file2
```

**Important: Note the `-s (--slurp)` flag, which puts files in the same array.**

Would get you:

```
{
  "value1": 200,
  "timestamp": 1382461861,
  "value": {
    "aaa": {
      "value1": "v1",
      "value2": "v2",
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    },
    "bbb": {
      "value1": "v1",
      "value2": "v2",
      "value3": "v3"
    },
    "ccc": {
      "value1": "v1",
      "value2": "v2"
    },
    "ddd": {
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    }
  },
  "status": 200
}
```

If you also want to get rid of the other keys (like your expected result), one way to do it is this:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1] | {value: .value}' file1 file2
```

Or the presumably somewhat more efficient (because it doesn't merge any other values):

```
jq -s '.[0].value * .[1].value | {value: .}' file1 file2
```

Comment: _NOTE_: the `-s` flag is important as without it the two objects are not in an array.

Comment: @SimoKinnunen Here we are merging two json files. Is it possible to have 1 json variable and other json file.
I tried but it seems not working for me!

Comment: If the individual files are sorted by a key, is it possible to preserve the order in the resulting file?

Comment: @SimoKinnunen I'm using this command:
"jq -s 'add' config.json other/*.json"
but when I do a "cat config.json" it is not merged. How can I put the output back to the file?

Comment: Note that `{value: .value}` can be shortened to just `{value}`.

Comment: if both json has the same key with different values, which one is preserved?

Comment: For @JayeshDhandha and future readers, merging one variable and one file can be done like this: `jq ". * $json_variable" json_input_file.json > json_output_file.json`

Comment: "if both json has the same key with different values, which one is preserved?" By standard, it should be the leftmost that is the 'base', and a dict to the left will overwrite any keys on a dict to the right.  But if both values are dicts, then it should repeat the merge process.  The only thing non-standard about this answer is that lists should overwrite each other, NOT append.  If you append lists there is no way to overwrite the list entirely.  that can easily become a serious problem

Answer (score 125):

Use `jq -s add`:

```
$ echo '{"a":"foo","b":"bar"} {"c":"baz","a":0}' | jq -s add
{
  "a": 0,
  "b": "bar",
  "c": "baz"
}
```

This reads all JSON texts from stdin into an array (`jq -s` does that) then it "reduces" them.

(`add` is defined as `def add: reduce .[] as $x (null; . + $x);`, which iterates over the input array's/object's values and adds them.  Object addition == merge.)

Comment: Is it possible to do the recursive merge (* operator) with this approach?

Comment: @DaveFoster Yes, with something like `reduce .[] as $x ({}; . * $x)` – see also [jrib’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36218044/1797912).

Comment: `echo '{"a":1}' | jq -s '[.[0], {"b":$b}] | add' --argjson b 2`

Answer (score 61):

Here's  a version that works recursively (using `*`) on an arbitrary number of objects:

```bash
echo '{"A": {"a": 1}}' '{"A": {"b": 2}}' '{"B": 3}' |\
  jq --slurp 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)'

{
  "A": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  "B": 3
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Works well when merging all files in a directory: `jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)' *.json`

Comment: My json content is an array of objects, so this works for me:
`echo $JSON_ONE $JSON_TWO | jq -s 'flatten | group_by(keys[]) | map(reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item))'`

Answer (score 48):

Who knows if you still need it, but here is the solution.

Once you get to the `--slurp` option, it's easy!

```
--slurp/-s:
    Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input,
    read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.
```

Then the `+` operator will do what you want:

```
jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' config.json config-user.json
```

(Note: if you want to merge inner objects instead of just overwriting the left file ones with the right file ones, you will need to do it manually)

Comment: Thanks… really useful point about how *right*-most inputs take precedence.

Answer (score 25):

No solution or comment given so far considers using `input` to access the second file. Employing it would render unnecessary the buildup of an additional structure to extract from, such as the all-embracing array when  using the `--slurp` (or `-s`) option, which features in almost all of the other approaches.

To merge two files on top level, simply add the second file from `input` to the first in `.` using `+`:

```sh
jq '. + input' file1.json file2.json
```

To merge two files recursively on all levels, do the same using `*` as operator instead:

```sh
jq '. * input' file1.json file2.json
```

That said, to recursively merge your two files, with both objects reduced to their `value` field, filter them first using `{value}`:

```sh
jq '{value} * (input | {value})' file1.json file2.json
```

```json
{
  "value": {
    "aaa": {
      "value1": "v1",
      "value2": "v2",
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    },
    "bbb": {
      "value1": "v1",
      "value2": "v2",
      "value3": "v3"
    },
    "ccc": {
      "value1": "v1",
      "value2": "v2"
    },
    "ddd": {
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/74uEFcXXL-)

Note that a solution which reduces only *after* the merge, like `. * input | {value}` would, is shorter in code but resurrects the "buildup of an additional structure to extract from" futility again, which may produce a lot of overhead if the parts eventually cut off get big.

In order to operate on more than two files, either accordingly use `input` multiple times, or programmatically iterate over all of them using `inputs` instead, as in

```sh
jq 'reduce inputs as $i (.; . * $i)' file*.json
```

Note that in either case the first file is always accessed via the input context `.` while `input(s)` only addresses the *remaining* files, i.e. starting from the second (unless, of course, the `--null-input` or `-n` option is given).

Answer (score 10):

First, {"value": .value} can be abbreviated to just {value}.

Second, the --argfile option (available in jq 1.4 and jq 1.5) may be of interest as it avoids having to use the --slurp option.

Putting these together, the two objects in the two files can be combined in the specified way as follows:

```
$ jq -n --argfile o1 file1 --argfile o2 file2 '$o1 * $o2 | {value}'
```

The '-n' flag tells jq not to read from stdin, since inputs are coming from the --argfile options here.

### Note on --argfile

The jq manual deprecates `--argfile` because its semantics are non-trivial: if the specified input file contains exactly one JSON entity, then that entity is read as is; otherwise, the items in the stream are wrapped in an array.

If you are uncomfortable using --argfile, there are several alternatives you may wish to consider.  In doing so, be assured that using `--slurpfile` does not incur the inefficiencies of the `-s` command-line option when the latter is used with multiple files.

Comment: jq has deprecated `--argile` for `--slurpfile`

Answer (score 10):

This can be used to merge any number of files specified on the command:

`jq -rs 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)' file1.json file2.json file3.json ... file10.json`

or this for any number of files

`jq -rs 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)' ./*.json`

Answer (score 5):

I didn't want to discard previous non-unique key in my objects

```
jq -n '{a:1, c:2}, {b:3, d:4}, {a:5,d:6}' |
jq -s 'map(to_entries)|flatten|group_by(.key)|map({(.[0].key):map(.value)|add})|add'
{
  "a": 6,
  "b": 3,
  "c": 2,
  "d": 10
}
```

or alternatively if you wanted to just keep an array of the values, remove the add after the extraction of the value `map(.value)|̶a̶d̶d̶`

```
jq -n '{a:1, c:2}, {b:3, d:4}, {a:5,d:6}' |
jq -s 'map(to_entries)|flatten|group_by(.key)|map({(.[0].key):map(.value)})|add'
{
  "a": [1, 5],
  "b": [3],
  "c": [2],
  "d": [4, 6]
}
```

Try removing each part of the command and see how each step modifies the array of objects... aka run these steps and see how the output changes

```
map(to_entries)
map(to_entries)|flatten
map(to_entries)|flatten|group_by(.key)
map(to_entries)|flatten|group_by(.key)|map({(.[0].key):map(.value)})
map(to_entries)|flatten|group_by(.key)|map({(.[0].key):map(.value)})|add
```