# Bash function: extraxt different fields from JSON with grep regex without using jq

Tags: json, bash

How can I write a bash function to extract a user defined field from JSON?

```
#!/bin/bash
JSON='{"field1":"field1Value","field2":"field2Value"}'
function getFieldValueFromJson {
    JSON_FIELD=$1
    JSON=$2
    regex=".\"$JSON_FIELD\":\".*\""
    key=$(echo $JSON |grep -Po $regex)
    echo $key
}
getFieldValueFromJson field1 $JSON
getFieldValueFromJson field2 $JSON
```

Output is:

> {"field1":"field1Value","field2":"field2Value"
>
> ,"field2":"field2Value"

Any idea how to solve this problem, if JSON is never pretty printed?

Edit:

OK, I can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) but I want to solve this just with grep and regex.

Comment: There are multiple issues possible. Do check http://shellcheck.net

Comment: In [Merge two json in bash (no jq)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38659763/) you can read some interesting comments on why it is not a good idea to try to parse JSON with Bash instead of using the tool for it (jq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `regex="\"$JSON_FIELD\":\"[^(\",)]*\""`

O/P:

```
"field1":"field1Value"
"field2":"field2Value"
```