# Deep JSON merge

Tags: json, jq

I have multiple JSON files that I'd like to merge into one.
Some have the same root element but different children. I don't want to overwrite the children but too extend them if they have the same parent element.
I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-file-using-jq), but it doesn't work:

```
jq: error (at file2.json:0): array ([{"title":"...) and array ([{"title":"...) cannot be multiplied
```

[Sample files and wanted result (Gist)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8032404a1ac78908d2ae15765e861859)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: warning, the sample files are invalid json as they have some dangling commas before }. (for instance after "key": "12345610")

Comment: Thanks. It should be fixed now, at least JSONLint says so now :)

Comment: If this is a `jq` question, please tag it as such.

Comment: It isn't necessarily, it's just what I found and tried.

Comment: Your question has the potential to be quite interesting but because the data has a recursive structure, it would be helpful if you could elucidate the nature of the merge that you are expecting.  Also, it would be helpful if you could clarify what you mean by "root element" in relation to the files and the array(s) they contain. Does each of the input files contain an array with exactly one JSON object in it?

Comment: @peak I suspect that by "root element", OP simply means relative nesting level in respect to merging.  Unfortunately my answer at this stage has only reproduced the desired output based on the structure of the test files as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution which uses `group_by(.key)` to decide
which objects to combine.  This could be a little simpler if `.children`
were more uniform. Sometimes it's absent in the sample data and sometimes it's the unusual value `[{}]`.

```
def merge:

    def kids:
        map(
            .children
          | if length<1 then empty else .[] end
        )
      | if length<1 then {} else {children:merge} end
    ; 

    def mergegroup:
      {
          title: .[0].title
        , key:   .[0].key
      } + kids
    ;

    if   .==[{}] then .
    else group_by(.key) | map(mergegroup)
    end
;

[ .[] | .[] ] | merge
```

When run with the `-s` option as follows

```
jq -M -s -f filter.jq file1.json file2.json
```

It produces the following output.

```
[
  {
    "title": "Title1",
    "key": "12345678",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "SubTitle2",
        "key": "123456713",
        "children": [
          {}
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "SubTitle1",
        "key": "12345679",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "SubSubTitle1",
            "key": "12345610"
          },
          {
            "title": "SubSubTitle2",
            "key": "12345611"
          },
          {
            "title": "DifferentSubSubTitle1",
            "key": "12345612"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If the ordering of the objects within the `.children` matters
then an a `sort_by` can be added to the `{children:merge}` expression,
e.g. `{children:merge|sort_by(.key)}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that will reproduce your desired result.  It's by no means automatic, It's really a proof of concept at this stage.

One liner:

```
jq -s '. as $in | ($in[0][].children[].children + $in[1][].children[0].children | unique) as $a1 | $in[1][].children[1] as $s1 | $in[0] | .[0].children[0].children = ($a1) | .[0].children += [$s1]' file1.json file2.json
```

Multi line breakdown (Copy/Paste):

```
jq -s '. as $in 
| ($in[0][].children[].children + $in[1][].children[0].children
| unique) as $a1
| $in[1][].children[1] as $s1
| $in[0]
| .[0].children[0].children = ($a1)
| .[0].children += [$s1]' file1.json file2.json
```

Where:

- `$in` : file1.json and file2.json combined input
- `$a1`: merged "SubSubTitle" array
- `$s1`: second subtitle object

I suspect the reason [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-file-using-jq) didn't work was because your schema is different and has nested arrays.

I find it quite hypnotic looking at this, it would be good if you could elaborate a bit on how fixed the structure is and what the requirements are.