# How to merge 2 json objects in R?

Tags: r, json

I've got 2 json objects and want to merge them into one unique objects in R.

Here the content of files:

object 1:

```
{
    "value": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}
```

object 2:

```
{
    "value": [
        "4",
        "5",
        "6"
    ]
}
```

expected results

```
{
    "value": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6"
    ]
}
```

I found similar questions in other language (such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-file-using-jq)), but I 'd like to do that in R (and I use jqr package).

Do you have any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Convert to data frames using `jsonlite::fromJSON`, combine, convert back to JSON with `jsonlite::toJSON`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To demonstrate @Gregor's advice, here is an example.

```
# Store JSON content as lists (lst1, lst2)
library(jsonlite);   
lst1 <- fromJSON(txt =
    '{
    "value": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}')    
lst2 <- fromJSON(txt =
    '{
    "value": [
        "4",
        "5",
        "6"
    ]
}')

# Merge lst1 and lst2 and output as JSON
toJSON(Map(c, lst1, lst2))
#{"value":["1","2","3","4","5","6"]}
```

Note, this works for the sample data you provide; if you have multiple keys (perhaps with some keys present in one JSON but not the other), you need to adjust your combination/merging strategy.

Answer (score 4):

I'm still getting my head around `jqr` too so there is likely a better, more concise solution without needing the extra `paste` at the end.

```
jqr::jq(paste0(js1, js2), ".value[]") %>%     ## extract the 'value's
  combine() %>%                               ## combine to a single JSON
  paste0('{"value":', .,"}")                  ## construct output

  # [1] "{\"value\":[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\"]}"
```