# Bash jq; build array using primary key

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a bash while do done loop in a loop that outputs using this
`echo "${KEY}: {\"${ATTRIBUTE}\": ${VALUE} }"`

Input part 1

```
"PKEY1": {"rank": 1 }
"PKEY2": {"rank": 2 }
"PKEY3": {"rank": 4 }
"PKEY4": {"rank": 3 }
```

Input part 2

```
"PKEY1": {"attr": "xyz" }
"PKEY2": {"attr": "foo" }
"PKEY3": {"attr": "bar" }
"PKEY4": {"attr": "abc" }
```

Input part 3,4,5,etc...

How can I get an output file or echo to look like this in short

```
{
"PKEY1": {"rank": 1, "attr": "xyz" },
"PKEY2": {"rank": 2, "attr": "foo" },
"PKEY3": {"rank": 4, "attr": "bar" },
"PKEY4": {"rank": 3, "attr": "abc" }
}
```

Comment: The output you have indicated you want is a JSON object, not a JSON array, so you might want to modify the TITLE of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is merge JSONs. If you are using 1.4+ you can use: `jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1 file2`

You can find more answers here: [How to merge 2 json file using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-file-using-jq)

Comment: Small nitpick his input is not really valid json.

Comment: easy fix, just wrap it in { } and add , if not the last line.

Comment: Side note that trying to directly output this to another file `>` doesn't work. Once again easy work around but it's a small bump I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as stated can be broken down into two parts:

1) parsing the text of `key : value` pairs into valid JSON;

2) constructing the output

Since the format of the key:value text is not clearly specified, I'm going to assume that each key:value pair occurs on a separate line, and that the key/value pair can be recovered using the def:

```
def parse: 
  capture("\"(?<k>[^\"]*)\" *: *(?<v>.*)") | [.k, (.v | fromjson)];
```

The second part of the problem is readily solved using the following generic def:

```
def add_by(s; f; g):
  reduce s as $x (null; .[$x|f] += ($x|g));
```

Putting the pieces together, we can write:

```
add_by(inputs | parse; .[0]; .[1])
```

### Invocation

With the above snippets in merge.jq, we can write:

```
jq -nR -f merge.jq part1.txt part2.txt part3.txt ...
```

### Variant

If your jq library already contains:

```
def aggregate_by(s; f; g):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|f] += [$x|g]);
```

then you could use the above def of `parse` as follows:

```
aggregate_by(inputs | parse; .[0]; .[1])
| map_values(add)
```