# Merge array by using inner property

Tags: json, jq

I have different language files like these:

**file1**

```
{
    "Pack": [
        {
            "id": "item1",
            "lang": {
                "en": {
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "item2",
            "lang": {
                "en": {
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**file2**

```
{
    "Pack": [
        {
            "id": "item1",
            "lang": {
                "sp": {
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and I need to merge the same ids by **lang** field. Final file should looks like:

```
{
    "Pack": [
        {
            "id": "item1",
            "lang": {
                "en": {
                },
                "sp": {
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "item2",
            "lang": {
                "en": {
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I think I should use something like more complex command but my starting point is:

```
jq -s '{ attributes: map(.attributes[0]) }' file*.json
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-file-using-jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want to read in all files as input, then combine all `Pack` items and aggregating them into groups by `id`, then take those groups and arrange them to the result you need.

```
$ jq -n '
{Pack: ([inputs.Pack[]] | group_by(.id) | map({id: .[0].id, lang: (map(.lang) | add)}))}
' file*.json
```

This results in:

```
{
  "Pack": [
    {
      "id": "item1",
      "lang": {
        "en": {},
        "sp": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "item2",
      "lang": {
        "en": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly with the sample files. I try to understand how it should be configured with more complex files.

Comment: Added other fields like in id: .[0].id but I think, should add a wildcard like *