# To output the merged file into a json file

Tags: json, jq, filemerge

Please let me know how to merge 2 json files into a new json file.

I used jq , and used the below command:

```
jq -s add file1.json file2.json > Output.json
```

But I am not getting the output in json ascii encode. While pasing I get an error :

> Failed to parse template: Error parsing JSON: invalid character 'ÿ' looking for beginning of value

Please let me know how can I output to json file in a windows command prompt.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: It looks like a reincarnation of this [bug](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/45). Perhaps `-s` is what exposes it.

Comment: So how can i resolve this?

Comment: JSON files should be UTF-8. With UTF-8 using a BOM is optional (which in my book makes it a requirement for readers to handle it, which is why I call this a bug). You could remove the BOM from the files outside of jq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `jq` doesn't require a valid JSON to read in a file, any JSON stream will do, I would suggest you just append the two files

`cat file1.json >> file2.json`

That said, I believe you can use `jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1 file2` to merge two JSON files

See: [How to merge 2 json file using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-file-using-jq)