# How can jq read lines from a file and create valid a JSON?

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I need help with creating a valid JSON file via jq which read lines from the file.

I have some text.txt file:

```
rabbit1-test1
rabbit1-test2
rabbit1-test3
```

And the bash-script:

```
VHOSTNAME=/
NODENAME=node1

input="test.txt"
while IFS= read -r line; do jq -n \
                  --arg a "$VHOSTNAME" \
                  --arg b "$line"  \
                  --arg c "$NODENAME" \
                  '{"data": [{"{#VHOSTNAME}": $a, "{#QUEUENAME}": $b, "{#NODENAME}": $c}]}' ;done < "$input"
```

But, when I run the script, the JSON isn't valid:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#VHOSTNAME}": "/",
      "{#QUEUENAME}": "rabbit1-test1",
      "{#NODENAME}": "node1"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#VHOSTNAME}": "/",
      "{#QUEUENAME}": "rabbit1-test2",
      "{#NODENAME}": "node1"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#VHOSTNAME}": "/",
      "{#QUEUENAME}": "rabbit1-test3",
      "{#NODENAME}": "node1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't understand why jq reads file incorrectly.
Please help me.

Comment: What output do you expect / hope for? This does look like valid JSON fragments; do you mean you want commas between them?

Comment: This does look like real valid JSON**S**, because you are running `jq` several times and getting several valid JSON.

Comment: The valid json is    {
  "data": [
    {
      "{#VHOSTNAME}": "/",
      "{#QUEUENAME}": "rabbit1-test1",
      "{#NODENAME}": "node1"
    },
    {
      "{#VHOSTNAME}": "/",
      "{#QUEUENAME}": "rabbit1-test2",
      "{#NODENAME}": "node1"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: How can i create one JSON for all line from my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use jq's split ?

```
jq -Rs --arg a '/' --arg c 'node1' '[ .[:-1] |
      split("\n")[] |
      { "{#VHOSTNAME}" : $a , 
        "{#QUEUENAME}": . , 
        "{#NODENAME}": $c } ] |
       { "data" : . }' sample.txt
```

Out:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#VHOSTNAME}": "/",
      "{#QUEUENAME}": "rabbit1-test1",
      "{#NODENAME}": "node1"
    },
    {
      "{#VHOSTNAME}": "/",
      "{#QUEUENAME}": "rabbit1-test2",
      "{#NODENAME}": "node1"
    },
    {
      "{#VHOSTNAME}": "/",
      "{#QUEUENAME}": "rabbit1-test3",
      "{#NODENAME}": "node1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: But, when i run jq not from file, but using "while", it doesn't work.

Comment: @perrfect why do you need a while ?

Comment: Because I need the script for rabbitMQ queues. And I want to get for command jq, all queues, via command - "rabbitmqctl list_queues", aren't using a .txt file.

Comment: still you shouldn't need a while. `rabbitmqctl list_queues | jq -Rs --arg a '/' --arg c 'node1' ....`

Comment: Sorry, but I need use "read lines". In rabbitMQ i have 1000 queues and i must read the queues  blocks of 100 pieces

Comment: @perrfect - I'm sorry, but you can't change the question incrementally and expect people to update their answer every time. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You can try to merge several files using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-objects-from-2-files-using-jq

Answer (score 0):

you can postprocess your output like so:

```
jq --slurp '{data: [.[].data[]]}'
```

https://jqplay.org/s/Y2N499onGFw

or use double jq: first one with `-R/--raw-input`, then another one with `-s/--slurp`, like this:

```
$ echo  -e "rabbit1-test1\nrabbit1-test2\nrabbit1-test3" | jq -R . | jq -s --arg a1 foo --arg a2 bar '[.[] | {x: $a1, y: ., z: $a2} ] | {data: .}'
{
  "data": [
    {
      "x": "foo",
      "y": "rabbit1-test1",
      "z": "bar"
    },
    {
      "x": "foo",
      "y": "rabbit1-test2",
      "z": "bar"
    },
    {
      "x": "foo",
      "y": "rabbit1-test3",
      "z": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```