# Create merged JSON array from multiple files using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have multiple JSON files `one.json`, `two.json`, `three.json` with the below format and I want to create a consolidated array from them using `jq`. So, from all the files I want to extract `Name` and `Value` field inside the `Parameters` and use them to create an array where the `id` value will be constructed from the `Name` value and `value` field will be constructed using `Value` field value.

*input:*
**one.json**:

```
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "id1",
      "Value": "one",
      "Version": 2,
      "LastModifiedDate": 1581663187.36

    }
  ]
}
```

**two.json**

```
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "id2",
      "Value": "xyz",
      "Version": 2,
      "LastModifiedDate": 1581663187.36

    }
  ]
}
```

**three.json**

```
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "id3",
      "Value": "xyz",
      "Version": 2,
      "LastModifiedDate": 1581663187.36

    }
  ]
}
```

*output:*

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "value": "one"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "value": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "value": "xyz"
  }
]
```

How to achieve this using `jq`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge 2 JSON objects from 2 files using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-objects-from-2-files-using-jq)

Comment: I tried using the above link, but couldn't reach the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `reduce` expression instead of slurping the whole file into memory (`-s`); by iterative manipulation of the input file contents and then appending the required fields one at a time.

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs.Parameters[] as $d (.; . + [ { id: $d.Name, value: $d.Value } ])' one.json two.json three.json
```

The `-n` flag is to ensure that we construct the output JSON data from scratch over the input file contents made available over the `inputs` function. Since `reduce` works in an iterative manner, for each of the object in the input, we create a final array, creating the KV pair as desired.