# Troubles merging many large json files to even larger file

Tags: json, linux, merge, jq, large-files

I have to merge ~1000 large json files (1M .. 500M) into a single file (~80GB) on Ubuntu 18.
According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-objects-from-2-files-using-jq), I use **jq** with

```
 jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)' ~/ml/train-*.json > train.json
```

which works quite nice for less smaller files.

The machine where merging happens is a 32 core server with 128 GB RAM. Alas, the task ends with a

```
Killed
```

statement, but in terms of memory, the resources should be sufficient. Can somebody please give me some advice how to manage this task? Thnx

Comment: You can invoke the streaming parser of `jq`, to avoid in-memory storage, but don't think `jq` has multiprocessing capabilities to make use of multiple cores. One way would be to use the command from jq - Cookbook - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#processing-huge-json-texts

Comment: Try `jq -cn --stream '
  def atomize(s):
    fromstream(foreach s as $in ( {previous:null, emit: null};
      if ($in | length == 2) and ($in|.[0][0]) != .previous and .previous != null
      then {emit: [[.previous]], previous: $in|.[0][0]}
      else { previous: ($in|.[0][0]), emit: null}
      end;
      (.emit // empty), $in) ) ;
  atomize(inputs)' ~/ml/train-*.json` and if the resulting file is too large to be stored on disk, pipe the output to `gzip` to compress i.e. `jq .. | gzip > result.gz` and then later use `zcat` to parse the compressed file

Answer (score 0):

Using -s is here both unnecessary and asking for trouble. You could try using `inputs` with the -n option instead.  Also I suspect you should be using `+` rather than `*`. That should also require less computer resources:

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $item (null; . + $item)'
```

The real question, though, is whether you **really** need to produce a single JSON entity, rather than a stream of JSON entities.

### Relevance of jq's streaming parser

jq's streaming parser (the one invoked with the `--stream` command-line option) is primarily targeted to reading very large JSON inputs, and is thus almost certainly irrelevant with respect to the problem being described.  On the other hand, it might be relevant when it comes to reading the generated file.

For the record, the other primary use of the streaming parser is handling inputs which include JSON objects with duplicated keys.  The regular jq parser uses a "right-most" semantics for such objects.