# parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 71, column 2

Tags: json, jq

I have two `json` files. If I am trying to add them into a single one, it is showing a parse error.

Can anyone explain how to rectify this?

The two files are: `config.json`

```
{   "config" :
    [
    {
    "IP": "10.97.05.212",
    "PORT": 80,
    "USERNAME": "admin",
    "ENABLE" : "False",
   
},
{
    "IP": "10.27.19.178",
    "PORT": 80,
    "USERNAME": "admin",

},
{
    "IP": "10.26.16.198",
    "PORT": 80,
    "USERNAME": "admin",

},
{
    "IP": "10.47.45.196",
    "PORT": 80,
    "USERNAME": "admin",
 
},

{
    "IP": "10.37.67.160",
    "PORT": 80,
    "USERNAME": "admin",


}

]}
```

`config1.json`

```
{
  "IP": "10.27.21.79",
  "PORT": 14564,
  "USERNAME": "admin",
}
{
  "IP": "10.27.21.79",
  "PORT": 14563,
  "USERNAME": "admin",
}
{
  "IP": "10.27.21.79",
  "PORT": 14566,
  "USERNAME": "admin",
}
```

`jq -n 'input | .config += [inputs]' config.json config1.json`

`jq  ' .[] += [ input ]' config.json config1.json`

`jq -s add config.json database.db`

`jq --slurp . config.json config1.json`

I have used above `jq` commands to do the task. But getting the same parse error:

`Expected value before ','`

Can anyone explain how to do rectify this error?

Comment: Please help with finding 71,2.

Comment: It is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-objects-from-2-files-using-jq

Comment: @OliverGaida, still it is getting the same error

Comment: @Yunnosch in config1.json after the first object there is  (  }, ), this is the 71,2

Comment: Would you say that config1.json is JSON or a stream of JSON values?

Comment: @Yunnosch they are stream of JSON values

Comment: @peak I think you need to elaborate.

Comment: The OP has clarified. So the solution is now obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since config1.json is a stream of JSON entities, you could use the --slurpfile option:

```
jq --slurpfile config1 config1.json '.config += $config1' config.json
```