# How to merge two JSON files using jq?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I need to merge two JSON files into one. The requirement is to replace values of keys existing in both files by values from second file. And add keys doesn't exist in first should be appended to the output JSON.

Is it possible to use `jq` to perform this operation?

First JSON:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "aaa": "aaa",
    "count": 0
}
```

Second JSON:

```
{
    "bbb": "bbb",
    "count": 1
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "aaa": "aaa",
    "count": 1,
    "bbb": "bbb"
}
```

Comment: `jq '. + input' first.json second.json` (use `*` instead of `+` if you need nesting).

Comment: Or `jq -s add first.json second.json`.

Comment: (Interestingly, `jq -n 'input + input' first.json second.json` does *not* work; it seems to read `second.json` first.)

Comment: Another answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-objects-from-2-files-using-jq

Comment: @chepner - jq and gojq differ in the order of evaluation of the arguments to `+`. For jq you could write: `input as $a | $a + input`

Answer (score -1):

`jq` provides “object multiplication” feature:

```
jq '. * input' file1.json file2.json
```

See the manual:

> ## Multiplication, division, modulo: *, /, and %
>
> […]
>
> Multiplying two objects will merge them recursively: this works like addition but if both objects contain a value for the same key, and the values are objects, the two are merged with the same strategy.